# Capture Response Attempting to Connect to Open SSH

Tags: ssh, bash

I want to be able to attempt to connect to a host using password authentication and store the server's response in a variable.  This is to see what hosts in my list accept passwords for their ssh services.

The problem is that I can not redirect this response to a variable:
root@ip's password:

The objective is to capture "root@ip's password:" as a string and store that in a variable.

Instead, the script hangs on root@ip's password: and expects input, preventing the loop from continuing to iterate.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

usernames=( root admin Administrator '' guest Anonymous )
response=

while read ip; do
    for user in "${usernames[@]}"; do
        response="$(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no $user@$ip)" 
        printf "The response is $response"
    done
done <ssh_telnet_open_ip_list
```

Edit, the code has been improved and this is what I have now:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "\nProbing SSH services:\n\n"
while read ip; do
    printf "Response from $ip:\n"
    ssh -v root@$ip -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "PreferredAuthentications=publickey" -I /dev/null 2>&1 | \
        grep "debug1: Authentications that can continue" | \
        cut -d : -f 3
    echo "------------------------------------------"
done <ssh_telnet_open_ip_list.txt
```

Example output:

```
Probing SSH services:

Response from ip:
 publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
------------------------------------------
Response from ip:
------------------------------------------
Response from ip:
 publickey,password
------------------------------------------
Response from ip:
 publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
------------------------------------------
Response from ip:
 publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
------------------------------------------
Response from ip:
 publickey,password
```

etc...

Comment: Your actual problem can be solved by redirecting stderr of ssh to stdout so you can pipe it. This is what the accepted answer does with `2>&1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The command

```
ssh -v user@ip -o "PreferredAuthentications=publickey" -I /dev/null 2>&1 | \
    grep "debug1: Authentications that can continue" | \
    cut -d : -f 3
```

## The output

```
publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,keyboard-interactive,hostbased
```

## How it works

- The SSH command connects, but only uses Public Key authentication, using /dev/null as the key
- The grep command extracts the log line with the supported ciphers
- The cut command extracts only the supported ciphers
- As the SSH connection cannot be made with no key, it closes, returning from the command straight away

## How to interpret the output

- If you see `keyboard-interactive`, then password auth is likely accepted
- If you see `publickey`, key based authentication is accepted

Comment: Your code seemed to work.  I modified it because I was still getting prompts such as:
The authenticity of host '111.222.333.444 (111.222.333.444)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is f3:cf:58:ae:71:0b:c8:04:6f:34:a3:b2:e4:1e:0c:8b.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
as shown in https://superuser.com/questions/125324/how-can-i-avoid-sshs-host-verification-for-known-hosts

so my code is now edited in my post.  Issue now is that some hosts are not giving me a response

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you will need a helper such as `sshpass` to do this.  You can see this detailed in @CSPei's answer to [Pass a password to ssh in pure bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24455773) at StackOverflow.

You would probably get a cleaner implementation using something like [Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) in Python.  The Client call will raise a more concise exception for you:

> *exception* paramiko.ssh_exception.**BadAuthenticationType**(*explanation*,
>   *types*)
>
> Exception raised when an authentication type (like password) is used,
>   but the server isn’t allowing that type. (It may only allow
>   public-key, for example.)